# Project Scenario where client requests a release in the middle of the sprint cycle

Tags: git, project-management

I am using git as the distributed revision control system to manage the code I develop for my project. As my project is agile we have regular sprint cycles.Our sprint cycle consists of 2 weeks.
Each code ticket has a feature branch created for it against the main branch called develop. Now when the code is reviewed it gets merged into the feature branch.

Problem is now when the client requests a release in the middle of the sprint. So now the develop branch may contain code which has feature branches committed to it but not yet tested. 
However you have to deliver the develop branch as a release to the client. So how to choose the feature branches you want included in that release ? As once you have merged the code to the develop branch(the one that gets release to the client) it gets very hard to remove that change from develop. What is the best project solution to this scenario ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you should continue working regularly. For this specific client, issue a specific release, which will be held in a specific branch. For example:

```
git checkout -b release_for_demanding_client develop
```

Now do all the magic you'd do in a regular release, only against release_for_demanding_client instead of develop. Release this to the client, and forget this branch ever existed. You can keep it for future reference, it is harmless. But don't continue developing on top of it, because as you said - the code there has not been reviewed yet, and may actually be different (after review fixes) in the develop branch.